# difference between <- and = in R with an example

Tags: r

I saw this as a question on datacamp.

(1)

```
vector <- c("a","b","c","d")
my_list <- list(vec=vector)
my_list
```

output:

$vec
[1]"a" "b" "c" "d"

(2)

```
vector <- c("a","b","c","d")
my_list <- list(vec<-vector)
my_list
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

So, I wondered how different they are and what's the different between <- and = in R.
I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html

Comment: When you type `list(vec<-vector)` the interior of the call to list is evaluated and then the result which is an unnamed vector with the value of `vector`. The name "vec"  is basically discarded.

Comment: Consider what you get with `matrix(1, ncol <- 2)`. It is probably not what you would expect.